# What's wrong in the following merging sorted array C++ code?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have been implementing a merging sorted array problem in C++, and found something strange happened in my code. So, here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode *next;
    ListNode(int x): val(x), next(NULL) {}
};

class Solution {
public:
    ListNode *mergeTwoLists(ListNode *l1, ListNode *l2) {
        if (l1 == NULL)
            return l2;
        else if (l2 == NULL)
            return l1;
        else
        {
            ListNode *head, *p;
            ListNode *h1 = l1;
            ListNode *h2 = l2;
            if (h1->val <= h2->val)
            {
                ListNode newNode(h1->val);
                head = &newNode;
                h1 = h1->next;
            }
            else
            {
                ListNode newNode(h2->val);
                head = &newNode;
                h2 = h2->next;
            }
            p = head;
            while (h1 != NULL && h2 != NULL)
            {
                if (h1->val <= h2->val)
                {
                    ListNode *Node = new ListNode(h1->val);
                    p->next = Node;
                    //p = p->next;
                    h1 = h1->next;
                }
                else
                {
                    ListNode *Node = new ListNode(h2->val);
                    p->next = Node;
                    //p = p->next;
                    h2 = h2->next;
                }
                p = p->next;
            }
            if (h2 != NULL)
            {
                while (h2 != NULL)
                {
                    ListNode *Node = new ListNode(h2->val);
                    p->next = Node;
                    p = p->next;
                    h2 = h2->next;
                }
            }
            else if (h1 != NULL)
            {
                while (h1 != NULL)
                {
                    ListNode *Node = new ListNode(h1->val);
                    p->next = Node;
                    p = p->next;
                    h1 = h1->next;
                }
            }
            return head;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    ListNode A1(1);
    ListNode A2(2);
    ListNode A3(3);
    ListNode A4(5);
    ListNode A5(7);
    A1.next = &A2;
    A2.next = &A3;
    A3.next = &A4;
    A4.next = &A5;
    ListNode B1(2);
    ListNode B2(4);
    ListNode B3(6);
    ListNode B4(8);
    ListNode B5(10);
    B1.next = &B2;
    B2.next = &B3;
    B3.next = &B4;
    B4.next = &B5;
    Solution solution;
    ListNode *x = solution.mergeTwoLists(&A1, &B1);
    while (x != NULL)
    {
        cout << x->val << endl;
        x = x->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code will get a runtime error. When I debugged it in codeblocks, I found everything normal in  class Solution.When it comes to main function, the while loop, something abnormal happened! x points to some strange address after one loop.
I'm wondering what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Here, in `mergeTwoLists`:

```
    if (h1->val <= h2->val)
    {
        ListNode newNode(h1->val);
        head = &newNode;
        h1 = h1->next;
    }
    else
    {
        ListNode newNode(h2->val);
        head = &newNode;
        h2 = h2->next;
    }
```

All of the other nodes you create on the heap with `new`, but here you create `newNode` on the stack. It's the first node of the list you're building, and it's a local variable of `mergeTwoLists`. When control passes out of the function, that first node passes out of scope. Then you access it and dereference its `next` in `main`, which is *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
while (x->next != NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thé first problem I see un jour code is that you keep adresses to stack allocated variables:

```
ListNode *head, *p;
// ...
if (h1->val <= h2->val) {
   ListNode newNode(h1->val);
   head = &newNode;
   h1 = h1->next;
   // newNode is destroyed here
   // thus head now points to invalid
   // data
} else {
   // same kind of code
}
p = head;
// p does not point to anything useful
```

This is what's wrong with your code.

Linked lists like the one you are implementing with `ListNode` are typically implemented using dynamically allocated nodes. You should try it here too. I suggest that you implement the most basic algorithms for your linked list (insertion, removal, search) before the merge, thus you'll be more likely to grope this structure.